# What is responsible for cutting an apple: pressure or force?

Tags: forces, pressure

To cut an apple, do I need more pressure or more force? When we want to destroy the intermolecular bonds, don't we need more force ?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a lot of force, but that does not necessarily mean you can cut the apple. Remember that $$P=F/A$$
So if you have a sharp knife you only need a small force because the pressure will be enough to slice through the apple.

The same counts for breaking a window: If you use the same force but a different surface area, the one with the lower surface area will be more likely to break the window.